# Google App Engine / Objectify Soft Delete

Tags: java, google-app-engine, objectify

I am using Objectify for my DAO layer on GAE, I wanna make most of my entity soft-delete-able, is it a good idea to make these entities extending a parent with isActive boolean or should I used embedded or should I just make it an interface isSoftDeleteable?

Reason I am asking is that it seems Objectify storing Entity with same parent class in same Entity kind (at least from what I see in the _ah/admin) and it may slow down the query when everything is under the same entity kind, maybe?

Which is the best way or if there is better way to do soft-delete in GAE?

Please advise and Thanks in advance!

Comment: There is only one Datastore. You probably meant same entity kind.

Comment: Yes...i meant same entity kind. Thanks Peter for the correction

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no single right answer to this question.  The optimal solution chiefly depends on what percentage of your entities are likely going to be in deleted state at any given time.

One option is to store a field like `@Index(IfTrue.class) boolean active;` and add this filter to all queries:

```
ofy.load().type(Thing.class).filter("size >", 20).filter("active", true)
```

The downside of this is that it requires adding extra indexes - possibly several because you may now need multi-property indexes where single-property indexes would have sufficed.

Alternatively, you can store a 'deleted' flag and manually exclude deleted entities from query results.  Less indexes to maintain, but it adds extra overhead to each query as you pull back records you don't want.  If your deleted entries are sparse, this won't matter.

One last trick.  You might find it best to store index a deleted date since it's probably most useful:  `@Index Date deleted;`  This lets you `filter("deleted", null)` to get the active items and also lets you filter by datestamp to get really old entities that you may wish to purge.  However, be aware that this will cause the deleted date to index into any multi-property indexes, possibly significantly increasing index size if you have a high percentage of deleted entities.  In this case, you may wish to `@Index(IfNull.class) Date deleted;` and use map-reduce to purge sufficiently old entities.

Comment: So you mean it is better to just add a boolean field to all Entity and index them instead of having an abstract/parent class and have all my Entity extending that?

Comment: Whether you add a boolean/date field to each deletable class or make each deletable class extend Deletable (which has the boolean/date) is pretty immaterial.  However, unless you have a compelling reason to model an 'isa' Deletable, this sounds like overengineering.  You may also run into single-inheritance problems.  You would probably be better off with a Deletable interface.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with StickFigure's answer. Take advantage of the difference between an "empty" index and a "null" index. The tradeoff is that each write will incur more datastore write operations - when you add an index, that's at least 2 additional write ops (ascending and descending) indexes that you need every time you update that value. When you delete the index, it's 2 more writes. Personally, I think this is worth while.

Query time should be fairly predictable whenever you do a query on a single property of an entity kind, because if you think about what's happening underneath the covers, you are browsing a list of items in sequential order before doing a parallel batch get of the entity data.